# Is there any W3C compatible Share & Follow plugin?

Tags: plugins, customization

I'm trying to build a fully W3C compatible blog. But I couldn't find a fully W3C compatible plugin. I want a simple plugin that provides share, tweet and like icons, sociable style. I don't want my readers to click a button to show share buttons, only buttons i want the plugin to provide. Any suggestions?

Comment: *@utdmr* - Can you define what you mean by *"W3C compatible?"*

Comment: i mean i want it to give no errors when i'm validate with w3c markup validation service. (http://validator.w3.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way is to skip plugin, add share buttons manually and then tweak.

There is usually some degree of flexibility to share buttons code. But plugins generally disregard that and go for defaults. If you want it to validate perfectly you will likely have to do it button by button.

Comment: are you saying don't use a plugin for it? wouldn't it be harder to add them to end of each post?

Comment: You can use `functions.php` file in theme for custom code tweaks. Then call your custom function in template or add via hook (really many ways to do this). I am not against plugin as method - I just think it is very unlikely to find public plugin that meets your validation requirement.

Comment: Okay than, now i think i'm going to write a simple new plug-in. Thank you, for your answer.